# Global application slow down after freeing memory while using Valgrind

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

I'm having an issue with my application that I only observe while I use Valgrind.
My program involves a large simulation.  When I unload the simulation portion of the program, while monitoring for errors with Valgrind it results in a permanent slowdown in the application.  I would have expected the opposite as unloading basically leaves my application with very little to do...  Valgrind reports no errors.  This slowdown does not occur (or is not observable) when I don't use Valgrind.

I have tried benchmarking various portions of my application using timers and they all seem to slow down fairly evenly across the board.  My application also contains multiple asyncronous threads that all slow down.  Processor usage does not seem to increase when viewed through the system monitor...

I'll note that I'm using openGL with fglrx drivers which are known to have some issues with Valgrind.

Should I be concerned about this even though it only occurs with Valgrind?  Is it likely that this slow down in caused by freeing a large amount of data while using Valgrind, or is it mostly likely indicative of serious bug in my code?

Basically I am trying to ascertain if this is entirely dependent on Valgrind usage or if Valgrind usage is amplifying the consequences of a bug in my code that otherwise is symptom free (but may  later cause me problems).

Comment: Using `valgrind` inevitably slows the process down. When you release space, the chances are that `valgrind` still has to look at memory accesses to see whether it is a reference to part of one of the freed chunks of memory, so it can tell if you're using pointers to freed memory. OTOH, it probably had to look at the memory accesses anyway, so I'm not wholly convinced that this accounts for the slowdown — but maybe there's a difference in the way it handles freed memory vs allocated memory. Anyway, performance under `valgrind` should be immaterial; you're not testing speed when you run with it.